# Appending a string inside for loop crashes ios device

Tags: ios, string, crash

I'm gathering data to an array in string format and one item is about 30 characters. When data collection is finished I try to combine all the strings into one big string, which is then written to a file. Combining strings is done inside for-loop, and it causes device to crash when number of data items gets somewhere over 4000. What is causing it and how to fix? Here's the code I have for appending strings:

```
NSString *content = @"";

for (int i=0; i<self.log.count; i++)
{
    content = [[content stringByAppendingString:@""] stringByAppendingString:(self.log)[i]];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you realize that the number of memory allocations and autoreleased objects you're creating by doing this. You may want to use an NSMutableString and append to that instead. Or just do what @Abizem said and join the array components.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to turn an array into a string there is an easier way to do it:

```
NSString *content = [self.log componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
NSString *content = @"";

for (int i=0; i<self.log.count; i++)
{
    content = [[content stringByAppendingString:@""] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(self.log)[i]]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To ensure the required amount of memory is allocated, I suggest you use a mutable string with an init for the length required.

```
-(NSString*)concantString:(NSArray *)incomingLog {
    int calculatedLength = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < [incomingLog count]; i++)
    {
        calculatedLength += [incomingLog[i] length];
    }

    NSMutableString *content = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:calculatedLength];
    for (int i=0; i < [incomingLog count]; i++)
    {
        content = (NSMutableString*)[[content stringByAppendingString:@""] stringByAppendingString:incomingLog[i] ] ;
    }
    return content;
}
```